# Prepared Statements Checking if row exists

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to Prepared Statements in Php and and wondering how you would best approach checking if a row already exists as I seem to be getting confused at this stage:

```
<?php 
include '../config.php'; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $stmt->execute();
    header('Location: ../login.php');   
} else {
    echo 'user already exists';
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

The above returns the `else` statement, if I switch them around it will insert again making use of the `else` statement and inserting the record but still not checking.

** UPDATE **

Here is my updated code for you to see after assistance below..

```
<?php 
include '../config.php'; 

ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt_check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =?");
$stmt_check->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt_check->execute();
if($stmt_check->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'user already exists';
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    // header('Location: ../login.php');
}    
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Prepared statements do not change anything. You'd do it exactly the same way you did before. Parameter binding is just a tool to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: That is my goal, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: please check first, any value return or not then use condition                                                                                 $stmt_check->execute();
$stmt_check->store_result();
$countRows = $stmt_check->num_rows; print $countRows; die;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*mysqli_num_rows* applicable to SELECT statement.

```
$stmt_check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =? AND password =?");
$stmt_check->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt_check->execute();
if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt_check) > 0)
```

***Updated Code***

```
<?php 

include '../config.php'; 

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt_check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =? AND password =?");
$stmt_check->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt_check->execute();
if($stmt_check->num_rows > 0){
  echo 'user already exists';
} else {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  header('Location: ../login.php');
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

***Quick Link***

- [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
- [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Which States,

> This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that
>   return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected
>   by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use
>   [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

**Edit 1**

Change

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt_check) > 0){
```

To

```
if($stmt_check->num_rows > 0){
```

See **Example2** of [PHP mysqli_num_rows() Function](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/PHP/MySQLi_Functions/PHP_mysqli_num_rows_Function.htm)

Comment: Sorry I am confused could you explain a little further for me?

Comment: It still makes use of the `else` statement. I have checked and removed all records from the database...?

Comment: @NanaPartykar I'm not sure, but is there not the `$stmt->execute()` statement missing after binding params?

Comment: @NanaPartykar i still get 'user already exists'... I am getting zero errors though

Comment: I have yes I copied it over to double check also

Comment: @danjbh two questions. First: Do you save your passwords in plaintext in the database? It seems so since you pass the POST_passwort directly to the query. Thats quite bad practice, you should always encrypt it. Second: Are you sure your posted data works? May but an `echo $email` or something before the statement to be sure your data is really posted to your script.

Comment: I will be making the encryption using `password_hash();` 100% the posted data works as it was posting before I tried to make the checks.

Comment: It isnt in there yet I am just firstly trying to understand how to check rows

Comment: The page just dies it does not show or create an error

Comment: @danjbh Check your database, I think the data you tried to insert should now be there. Your only problem will be the `header('Location: ../login.php');` I think. Does it redirect? I mean, is the 404 on the .../login.php ? Check if the redirect is done properly. For try out you can also replace your redirect with an `echo "success";`

Comment: See whether data enters into database or not @danjbh. Because, that problem will get solve now. Problem seems to be with `header('Location: ../login.php');`

Comment: i am checking the database, there is zero records. It isnt even getting to that point now the page seems to just die as if there is a syntax error?

Comment: I have commented out the header location and tried to echo out a message but it isn't even getting to that point. the reason why it would fail on a header redirect is because you added white space to the top of the code.

Comment: This code checks if the combination of email **AND** password already exist. I think OP only wants to check on email?(Since it's a check on if the user already exists)

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your script. It will display errors. Then post the error please @danjbh
Edit: Good points Loko. Didin't thought about that.

Comment: @Loko correct I didnt spot that I will remove the password check

Comment: I get this `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Root/lr-project/lib/register.php on line 14` and 

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Root/lr-project/lib/register.php on line 21`

Comment: Please check my whole code. See the edit1 section too in my answer. You are mixing object oriented and procdeural style @danjbh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132172/discussion-between-danjbh-and-nana-partykar).

Comment: What was the problem @danjbh?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Ill explain in my question incase others come across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is my updated code, please try

```
  <?php 

include '../config.php'; 

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt_check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =? AND password =?");
$stmt_check->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt_check->execute();
$stmt_check->store_result();
$numberofrows = $stmt_check->num_rows;

if(($numberofrows) > 0)
  echo 'user already exists';
} else {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  header('Location: ../login.php');
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This also returns the else statement back to me, something fishy is going on here..

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()

```
<?php include '../config.php'; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
$stmt->execute();

if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0)
{
    header('Location: ../login.php');   
}
else
{
    echo 'user already exists';
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I still get back the else statement, there is 100% nothing in the table that could be causing this...?

Comment: This code won't work, since you pass `$email`and `$password` to the first query without having defined it. He put the `$_POST` part in the if function, so the first query will always return nothing since `$email` and `$password` is empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php include '../config.php'; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
$result = $stmt->execute(); // this return a bool: true if row affected otherwise false

if($result)
{
    header('Location: ../login.php');   
}
else
{
    echo 'user already exists';
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: with this the else statement is not executed

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some explanation to your code, so others can understand clearly.